# Uncaught TypeError with JQuery ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery

Although my script works as it is supposed to I am getting this error in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'taken' of null
```

I have tried to work out what this message means and from what I can tell it means that the element 'taken' doesn't exist in the DOM but I'm not sure how this is relevant when it is an element created in an if loop in a ajax call?

The ajax call

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"includes/multi_check.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            if(response.taken == 'yes'){
                var taken_by = response.taken_by;
                window.location.href ="http://www.x-rayqa.co.uk/index.php"
            }
        }
    }); 
}, 5000); //5 seconds
```

The php called (`multi_check.php`)

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userID = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$db_token = $row['session_token'];
$taken_by = $row['taken_over'];
$taken = 'no';

if($_SESSION['session_token'] != $db_token){
    $_SESSION['taken_over_by'] = $taken_by;
    $taken = 'yes';
    $output_array = array(
        'taken_by' => $taken_by,
         'taken' => $taken,
         'session' => $_SESSION['session_token'],
         'orig_session' => $test,
         'user' => $id
   );

 echo json_encode($output_array);
```

Comment: show the json response of ajax call what is returned?

Comment: The error means that the 'response' object does not exist. Look into that.

Comment: what is the output of `$output_array` ?

Comment: @karthikr there is not output

Comment: Is there a JSON-output also when the if-condition is not met? Else the response might be null, as stated in the error message.

Comment: @fast that was indeed the cause of the error, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `response` is null, accessing a property from `null` would lead to this issue.

Try this instead:

```
if (response && response.taken ) {
    //...
}
```

This way, you would check for truth value of the object `response`, and then access a property if it evaluates to `true`

Answer (score 3):

These are the lines of code which you need to look at -

```
success: function(response){
    if(response.taken == 'yes'){
```

What the error message says is that the 'response' is null. So, response.taken is unreadable.

As mentioned in comment change the line to the following to fix the error -

```
if(response && response.taken === 'yes')
```

Comment: `response` is still `null`. This wont work. `if(response && response.taken === 'yes')` would work.

Comment: @karthikr there is only a response if the argument in the multi-check.php was true, failing that there was no response and that is what caused the error.  Your suggestion of checking if there was a response fixed the problem so if you add it as an answer I will accept it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should optimize, improve the way you return back your JSON object. A better way would be to do this:

```
header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
echo json_encode($output_array);
exit;
```

As others have mentioned, you should check out what's being returned as a response.

```
success: function(response){
    console.log(response); // What is the output of this in your JavaScript console?
    if(response.taken == 'yes'){
```

A good way to debug this is using the "Network" tab in the Chrome Developer Tools. It will show you exactly what your PHP file returned.

[image]

Overall, it seem you might be having a problem in your PHP side and not in your JavaScript side. What is the output of your PHP if you call it directly?

In order to get a more clear response to your AJAX request, you might want to add some safeguards to you PHP, like:

```
if (!$output_array) {
    $output_array = array('success' => 0);
} else {
    $output_array['success'] = 1;
}
header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
echo json_encode($output_array);
exit;
```

Then in your JavaScript you can check the output of this variable:

```
success: function(response){
    if (response.success === 1){
        // Handle success
    } else {
        // Handle failure 
    }
```

Comment: the error was caused by the lack of response because the argument in the php was false